# "doctrine:schema:validate". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

Tags: symfony, docker-compose

Can someone educate me on how to run symfony migrations at the shell in a docker container environment?

I login to my app container

```
$ docker exec -it 79dcd1240fdf /bin/bash
```

and run

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

only receive

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I'm able to login to my database container and access the database from there, so am confused since the db exists?

```
$ docker exec -it bd96edcb1164 /bin/bash

I have no name!@bd96edcb1164:/$ mysql -h localhost -P 4307 -u andy -ppassword symfony_red
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8
Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

MariaDB [symfony_red]> show databases
 -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| symfony_red        |
| test               |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [symfony_red]>
```

Here's my docker config:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:
 myapp:
 image: 'docker.io/bitnami/symfony:1-debian-10'
 ports:
   - '8000:8000'
 volumes:
   - '.:/app'
 depends_on:
   - mariadb
 mariadb:
  image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10'
  environment:
   - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
   - MARIADB_USER=andy
   - MARIADB_DATABASE=symfony_red
   - MARIADB_PASSWORD=password
  ports:
   - "4307:3306"
```

and my .env config:-

```
# .env.local
DATABASE_URL=mysql://andy:password@localhost:4307/symfony_red?serverVersion=5.7
```

I already tried switching `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` - that just toggles another error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

help?

Comment: did you use `docker-compose up` to start your setup? also, your docker-compose.yml looks quite different to the one on https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/symfony

Comment: Yes, I'm using `docker-compose up` and with the `docker-compose.yml` you reference on the https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/symfony link I add in those missing values only the same error persists?

Comment: okay, so I expect one of two things to happen, first, when connecting to mysql from the symfony container, it won't work with your connection string and not even your mysql command that worked in the mysql container. I would assume from the bitnami/symfony container doc, that instead of `localhost` the mysql container can be reached from within the symfony container via `[...]@mariadb:4307/[...]` (so not localhost, but "mariadb"), but I might be wrong

Comment: You were right, it WAS the `mariadb` string which ultimately fixed it. Fantastic! thankyou.